# About responseBody in Android

Tags: java, php, android, post, echo

It's a simple question. I've an Android Application communicating with a PHP server via POST method. I POST some parameters, and server answer with Echo. If server does more than one Echo, how to get the answer in Android of all this echoes?

Comment: are the multiple echoes coming instantly or after intervals?

Comment: one echo after another

Answer (score 0):

You should return your data w/ JSON instead of just echo'ing it out. That way, you'll have more control over the return data. i.e. Change:

```
if($something){
    echo 'Output!';
}
if($somethingElse){
    echo 'More output!';
}
```

into something like:

```
$response = array();
if($something){
    $response[] = 'Output!';
}
if($somethingElse){
    $response[] = 'More output!';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

... and then parse the JSON.